# Node.js http server: what happens to the unread body of the POST request?

Tags: node.js, http, express

The situation is as follows:

HTTP connection option: Connection: keep-alive.

1. An HTTP client sends a POST request with invalid authentication. The POST request has a fair amount of the content in the body - for example, 80KB.
2. The HTTP server (which uses express and http-auth node module) reads the request header (but not the body) and decides that this request is not the authorized one, and sends the 401 response.
3. Now the body is still unread by the server, but the TCP connection is not closed since the HTTP connection option is Connection: keep-alive.

What happens now? Will the unread body be silently discarded, or the application code must explicitly read and discard it to receive further HTTP requests from current TCP connection?

**UPDATE**

I've written simple test scripts.

Client:

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

function doIt()
{
    var postData;
    (function ()
    {
        var i, baseData;
        var dup = 6700;

        baseData = 'dummy text';
        postData = '';
        for (i = 0; i < dup; i++)
            postData += baseData;
        console.log('data length = ' + postData.length);
    })();

    var agent = new http.Agent(
        {
            keepAlive: true,
            keepAliveMsecs: 30000,
            maxSockets: 1
        });

    var options =
    {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '9876',
        path: '/',
        method: 'POST',
        headers:
        {
            'Content-Type': 'plain/text',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
        },
        agent: agent
    };

    var count = 1;
    function doReq()
    {
        console.log((count++) + ' =========================');
        var req = http.request(options, function (res)
        {
            console.log('status code = ' + res.statusCode);
            console.log('headers', res.headers);
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (chunk)
            {
                console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
            });
            res.on('end', function ()
            {
                setTimeout(doReq, 1000);
            });
        });
        req.on('socket', function (socket)
        {
            console.log('socket.keepAliveTestId', socket.keepAliveTestId);
            if (socket.keepAliveTestId === undefined)
                socket.keepAliveTestId = Date.now();
        });
        req.on('error', function (err)
        {
            console.log('error:', err);
        });
        req.write(postData);
        req.end();
    }

    doReq();
}

doIt();
```

Server:

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);

app.use(function (req, res, next)
{
    console.log(req.headers);
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        next(new Error('test error'));
    }, 1);
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next)
{
    console.log('returning');
    res.status(401).end();
});

httpServer.listen(9876);
```

With this test program, the following behaviour wwas observed:

With connection: keep-alive, when dup >= 6700(that is, the size of the POST data >= 67,000 bytes), the server no longer responds from the 2nd request.

By this, I can guess that the Node.js's http server code does not explicitly eat out the rest of the POST data, but it can accidentally does it when it reads the whole POST data with the header by one socket read and hands it to the http parser, or something similar occurs.

Comment: Who says the body is never read?  What reference do you have for that?

Comment: @jfriend00 I meant that the application does not read the body. (Maybe the http module actually read it)

Comment: So, it appears you have a supposition that nobody reads the body data off the TCP socket but you don't know if that's actually true.  It seems you should start by figuring out if that is actually true or not.  If the http library queues that data in memory (waiting for it to be read by someone from the incoming stream), then you would already have your answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've updated the question with some research result.

Answer (score 0):

Every request is a new request. It has nothing to do with the previous requests nor with the future ones.

**For keep alive:**
As soon you response from the server, the next request will come from the queue (only for the same TCP connection).

**For without keep-alive:**
It will create connection every time you will request to server.

So you don't need to discard anything, just response for the request.

Comment: The point is that since TCP provides ordered delivery of packets, if a large amount of body data was sent and nobody read it, then it is in the way on the TCP connection of the next request that might come over the connection and it has to get out of the way before another request could be read over that same connection.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm trying to find the relevant code that reads and discards the remaining body in the Node's http source code, but currently couldn't find one.